# AB Testing - No remainder - refreshed DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to send to a DE that gets refreshed every 8 hours, the evaluation period is 3 days.

I am not sending to a remainder and the send is going out on the same date/time- is it necessary to stop the DE updating during the evaluation period ? I was told I only needed to do this when testing different dates/times.

Looking to make sure I set up the correct process with end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter as you won't have a remainder to send to (this would matter), but Salesforce advises keeping the [data extension static during an A/B test](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_abtest_configure.htm&type=5).

If you're not having a remainder, my suggestion would be to do this via Journey Builder. You set it up on a 'run-once' schedule, then use a random split activity to split your audience as you wish.

Then check the results for each email according to your schedule (admittedly there's more manual effort in the analysis to match the 3-day snapshot if it's absolutely necessary).